# Make Maven Failsafe exit with non-zero status when tests fail?

Tags: maven, emacs, maven-failsafe-plugin

How can the [Maven Failsafe plug-in](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) be made to exit with a non-zero exit status if any test fails?  By default it seems to exit with a zero exit status no matter if tests succeeded or failed.

This is a problem when running integration tests from an editor (like Emacs) that checks the exit status of the build command: If it sees a zero exit status, it assumes executing the tests succeeded. If it sees a non-zero exit status, it flags that visibly to the user. This cannot be used if Maven Failsafe always just exits with a zero exit status and the user is forced to review the test execution logs to discover if tests failed, which is a time-consuming task.

The command used is: `mvn test-compile failsafe:integration-test -Dit.test=FooIT`

Comment: You should use the maven-failsafe-plugin:verify goal..which handles that...

Comment: khmarbaise: Thanks, that seems to have been exactly what I was looking for (`mvn test-compile failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify`). Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: Are you really calling this on command line? What not binding it correctly to the life cycle and simply calling `mvn verfiy`?

Comment: khmarbaise: The integration tests are bound to the `verify` lifecycle phase as recommended. However, for a faster development cycle when developing integration tests, I want to execute only the integration tests and none of the heavy lifecycle phases that precede it, so I invoke the Failsafe goals directly.

Comment: Why not running the IT from your IDE?

Comment: I'm using a development environment (Emacs) that interfaces with the tests using processes, so invoking the `mvn` command is the way to go here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125438/discussion-between-valko-sipuli-and-khmarbaise).

Comment: @khmarbaise You might want to run a flaky integration test over and over again to see whether or not it fails and under which conditions. That's hard to do in an IDE without changing test code and whatnot, but easy in bash:
`let i=0; let failure=0; while true ; do let i++; time mvn  failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify -Dit.test=ResponsibleAttenderExpirerITest -Dparallel=classesAndMethods || let failure++;   printf "\nFailed %d of %d runs\n" $failure $i; done`

Comment: Why do you:  `That's hard to do in an IDE without changing test code ` ? Why? Can't you run your IT in your IDE?

Comment: @khmarbaise maybe they are running the tests in a CI/CD pipeline after a deploy to see if the deploy was successful?

Answer (score 1):

Just posting the answer from the comments for posterity:

### Add the failsafe:verify goal

Typically `mvn  failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify -Dit.test=MyITest`

### Example script for stats on a test

Example of running a flaky integration test over and over again while skipping all the other lifecycle tasks (given that everything has compiled already):

```
let i=0; 
let failure=0; 
while true ; do 
  let i++; 
  time mvn --quiet failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify \
     -Dit.test=ResponsibleAttenderExpirerITest \
     -Dparallel=classesAndMethods -Dfailsafe.printSummary=false \
     || let failure++;   

  printf "\nFailed %d of %d runs\n" $failure $i; 
done
```